# Physics HL Nov 2022 - Hovering Aircraft: underlying problem model

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This is the setup of a Physics HL paper of past year:

[image]

I would like to understand the model underlying this problem.
From the [solutions](https://youtu.be/N-G1GQylT_I) I can find worked out in that video for instance, this is the only way it can make sense:

- the problem considers air as an object of a certain mass that gets accelerated from rest to a final velocity. It is basically a one dimensional motion, frictionless, no potentials, despite gravity acting on the *other* object (the aircraft).
- work is done on that mass to accelerate it, but afterwards the motion of air is constant velocity, no work done, frictionless...
- the final situation is that the momentum acquired by the mass at certain velocity is the result of the average force exerted to accelerate it and this force equals the pull of gravity on the aircraft + package for eternity afterwards.
- there is some mechanism, the blades maybe?, that converts the momentum of the air mass into a force exerted on the aircraft to keep it hovering
- the energy associated to the air mass is purely kinetic, gravity is neglected

Are these the right assumptions?
(This bends my mind really hard)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see where you are getting a transient from in this problem. It's a simple static analysis of the helicopter equation.

Comment: This is a common/standard "force equals rate of change of momentum problem" with no transients, the rate at which air is pushed down in kg/s, etc.  There is no "hidden agenda".

Comment: So, from your answer, I understand that the correct interpretation to get the force is:
$$F = m \cdot \dfrac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$
is my understanding correct?
If so, I am wondering: after the first second, what happens to the velocity of the air? Does it stay constant, does it increase?